# how do i make something like this : if my count reach 100 , then the message will appear?

Tags: javascript, if-statement

```
let countEl = document.getElementById("count-el")

let con = document.getElementById("cc")

console.log(countEl)
console.log(con)

let count = 0;

function increment() {
    count = count + 1 `enter code here`
    countEl.innerText = count
    console.log(count)
}
```

Comment: After incrementing, check the value of `count` and display your message if the condition is met.

Comment: How are you controlling the increment? Is it `setInterval` or `setTimeout`? A click on a button? At some point you need a condition that checks the count against 100, but you're not currently doing that. You need a [mcve] in your question that can answer these issues.

Comment: Essentially, as @EmielZuurbier mentions, you need a `if` statement that conditions your `count` var and to handle that message.

Comment: Forgot to mention, I use onclick funtion

Comment: `if (count > 100) { // do this } else { // do that }`

Comment: yeah, i have use this but it still won't work: if ( count > 10) {
    console.log("done")
}